# Get Html Content from xml using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to get  content from this XML .Can You Please Suggest Me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"     xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn"  xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0">
 <entry>
  <content type="html">&lt;p dir="ltr"&gt;
  &lt;strong&gt;Consumer demand for tiger parts poses the largest threat to tiger survival.over 1000 tigers have been killed to traffic their parts to meet consumer demandin Asia&lt;/strong&gt;.
&lt;/p&gt;</content>
</entry>
</feed>
```

javascript :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://greenhouse.lotus.com/forums/atom/topics?communityUuid=b73c26c9-175f-4a7b-938d-86da3118db95",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

$(xml).find('feed').each(function(){

     $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){

     var summary= $(this).find('content').text();
```

});
});

Comment: Is this XML in the DOM, or are you reading it from a file or Ajax call?

Comment: Did you try using `find`? What have you tried? What specific problems are you having?

Comment: I am using XML URl for this one

Comment: Yeah I have tried with find()

Comment: Do you want to get the content of the XML file and display it in a HTML page? If yes, then AJAX is the keyword. Edit: OK, I see you're using AJAX.

Comment: There are two typos in the code example: `survival.over` should be `survival. Over` and `demandin` should be `demand in`.

Comment: @cezar I didnt get U!!!

Comment: The typos are in the long sentence within the element `content`. And now you messed also with the braces in your jQuery example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the .parseXML() method is what you need.

The documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/